# Get id's of all the buttons within parent layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android app in java with eclipse.

I have 2 Relative layouts within my XML. One layout has 2 buttons within it and the other has 3 buttons. I'm trying to some how retrieve all the id's of the buttons in the relative layout that has the two buttons inside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through parent view to get all child views

```
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
for(int i=0; i < parentView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View childView = parentView.getChildAt(i);
    int resID = childView.getId();
}
```

Comment: where exactly do I specify the parent view that I want to retrieve the ids from and thank you so much for answering

Comment: as for the code you provide it should be ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

Comment: yeah I just figured it out thank you so much god bless you and your family