# android studio how to set some TextViews id's with for

Tags: android

i want to set lots of Edit Texts id's and i don't know how to get those id's.

```
EditText[] texts;
for(int i=0;i++;i<15){
tests[i]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.   )
}
```

my Edit Text id's:

```
et1,et2,et3,...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18805401/8283938 Maybe this works, I don't have tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create a empty list of EditTexts

then use this code and send them rootView of Your Layout to find all EditTexts :

```
    private List<EditText> editTexts; //global Scop

 private void findAllEditTexts(ViewGroup group) {
        for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
            View view = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                if (editTexts == null)
                    editTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();
                editTexts.add((EditText) view);
            } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup && (((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount() > 0)) {
                findAllEditTexts((ViewGroup) view);
            }
        }
    }
```

now in editTexts List you have all EditTexts :)